# Handle dynamic parameter when null in the stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

I working on a stored procedure in redshift. I see that when parameters passed are `NULL` to the Execute statement in stored procedure. It fails with `cannot execute a null string`.

Please give me insights on how to solve the problem.

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE outer_proc() LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
cond_holder RECORD;
iter RECORD;
BEGIN

  drop table if exists tmp_direction_comms;

  create temporary table  tmp_direction_comms as select distinct code from direction_coms;

  DROP TABLE if exists final_direction_comms;

  EXECUTE  'CREATE TEMP TABLE final_direction_comms
     (
    code varchar(100),
    direction varchar(100),
    dir_flg  Boolean
    )';

  FOR iter IN select code from tmp_direction_comms LOOP
    RAISE INFO 'code is %', iter.code;

    SELECT INTO cond_holder distinct condition FROM mapping where  code = iter.code;

    RAISE INFO 'engmnt_cd is %', cond_holder.condition;

    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO final_direction_comms select code, direction, case when  NVL('||cond_holder.condition||',false) then true else false end as dir_flg
    from direction_coms where code = '''||iter.code||'''';

  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO final_direction_comms select code, direction, 
           case when  NVL('||cond_holder.condition||',false) then true else false end as dir_flg
              from acp_edw.stg_edw.direction_coms where code = '''||iter.code||'''';
```

There are two variables that can be NULL - `iter.code` or `cond_holder.condition`. The `cond_holder.condition` is wrapped by `NVL`, but `NVL` is inside in result string, not in generating expression.

Second big issue is a vulnerability against SQL injection. Probably you should to do:

```
 EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO final_direction_comms select code, direction, 
           case when  ' || NVL(cond_holder.condition, false) ' || then true else false end as dir_flg
              from acp_edw.stg_edw.direction_coms where code = $1'
    USING iter.code;
```

I am not sure if Redshift has support for `USING` clause. If not, then you should to use `quote_literal` function:

```
'... where code = ' || quote_literal(iter.code);
```

Comment: I believe it is the pipe symbol || causing entire string to become null. can i know if there is any other way.

Comment: @kites - then the null should be in `iter.code`. There cannot be any other possibility. try to push before execute - `RAISE NOTICE '% %', cond_holder.condition is null, iter.code is null`;

Comment: @kites - `||` is null sensitive. Postgres has `concat` function, but redshift is too old. Maybe you can use `COALESCE` function istead `NVL`

Comment: NVL and coalese both seem to be identical in redshift. I get this error
COALESCE types character varying and boolean cannot be matched;

Comment: @kites, for this case, you can write `'false'` instead `false`.

Comment: Thanks @Pavel Stehule. That helped.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out iter.code being null as well. I added other row (null-e) in src table. I believe now it is failing at iter.code. Redshift doesn't have USING clause. alternatively, I used where code = ' || quote_literal(iter.code); as well. but || is making it execute null again and getting the error.

Comment: @kites - postgres has function `quote_nullable`. But again - you can use `coalesce` - `coalesce(quote_literal(iter.code), '')`